# Deep Learning scipy.misc syntax error on imread.image.io

Tags: python, deep-learning, scipy, feature-extraction

I have a piece of python code that is intended to extract letters and label each region that contains an image.
I'm using google colab

I get the following error:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
      1

----> 2 image = imageio.imread('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/985792111713947648/7YD1ZYpe_400x400.jpg')
     3 
     4 
     5

NameError: name 'imageio' is not defined```

Heres the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from scipy.misc import imageio.imread,imresize
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.morphology import label
from skimage.measure import regionprops

image = imageio.imread('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/985792111713947648/7YD1ZYpe_400x400.jpg')



#apply threshold in order to make the image binary
bw = image < 120

# remove artifacts connected to image border
cleared = bw.copy()
clear_border(cleared)

# label image regions
label_image = label(cleared,neighbors=8)
borders = np.logical_xor(bw, cleared)
label_image[borders] = -1

print(label_image.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(6, 6))
ax.imshow(bw, cmap='jet')
```

Comment: The first line of code (excluding imports) calls imageio.imread but python doesn't know where it can get imageio. Maybe you're missing an import or it was a typo.

Comment: that's what i thought so I tried. `from scipy.misc import image.ioimread,imresize` and `from scipy.misc import image , ioimread,imresize`. I then got a syntax error from those lines

Comment: Edit your post with the new information (code and error) please.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a function from a package you haven't imported yet. First you need to install imageio in your system (pip install imageio) and then include it in the code (and removing the other imread). The new code will be:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.morphology import label
```

If you're going to use imresize you will need to install pillow.